# Power in, and power to light at one 3 way?

Tags: electrical

In an ideal 4-way situation my understanding is you feed the 3-way switch with power in then go to 4-way then to next 3-way then to lights.  Is it okay to go to lights at the first switch? Besides the extra wire being there in that box?

If a dimmer is involved it's typically at the 3-Way switch which goes to lights, correct?

Comment: Do you have lights branched off several of the boxes, or just the first one? Also, what make and model of dimmer were you planning on using?

Comment: It depends how many conductors are available between each location.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'm not sure what you mean branched off several of the boxes? Which boxes? Current lights are not connected to a switch yet as I am deciding which switch to feed the series of lights.  This is all 12-2 between lights and 12-3 between switches.

Comment: @Nic -- ah, never mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to do this, you need to feed the hot wire to the far 3-way switch and connect the neutral directly to the lamp. You must wire so that the hot wire is switched and the neutral is unswitched. This is for safety (and code compliance) so that there is no power to the lamp when the switches are off.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem doing that.   Any number of *n*-way switches, together,  considering just the switches and their messengers... are the equivalent of a simple switch.

In your case, power and lamp come through the first switch location, then the string of switches are a spur off of that.  That makes it simplest of all, since the entire spur of switches is electrically similar to a single switch.

Comment: Assuming it's 12-3 between three switches, with the 4 way being the middle switch, then I'm fine either running power from the first switch to the light series or power from the last switch to the light series then?

Comment: Assuming it's 12-3 between three switches, with the 4 way being the middle switch, then I'm fine either running power from the first switch to the light series or power from the last switch to the light series then?

Comment: Yes, in an *n*-way circuit, 2 wires are the messengers and the other is the return,  it doesn't matter whether the return brings back switched-hot to box 1, or carries neutral to the last box from whence the light branches,   You just have to be careful to reserve white for neutral where that applies.   I like to tape my messenger wires yellow or blue.  By which I mean both messengers the same color, since they are the same thing and interchangeable.

Comment: when powering a light from the same 3-way that 1) has power coming in and 2) goes to the 4-way switch, it just means I use the neutral wire as a messenger wire instead, correct? edit: Just saw you said reserve neutral, which means no I can't do that.